# How can i further customize my react router dom NavLink activeStyle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

so I have this simple not very well designed navbar with react router

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Router>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><NavLink to="/" exact activeStyle={{color:"green"}}>Home</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/about" activeStyle={{color:"green"}}>about</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/contact" activeStyle={{color:"green"}}>contact</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <Route path="/" exact render={() => <h1>Home</h1>}/>
      <Route path="/about" render={() => <h1>About</h1>}/>
      <Route path="/contact" render={() => <h1>Contact</h1>}/>



      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

That's a very simple use of `NavLink`. Im wondering how can I add more styles to it for example how do I access the `::before` & `::after` element of the `<a>` tag from the to add underline animation to it. I know how to do that in CSS but I'm very confused how do I add that in `NavLink`. I will very much appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [activeClassName](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string) instead of style and manipulate the element using the class selector in css for additonal styling changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use styled-components and do something like this:

```
const MenuLink = styled(NavLink)`
    // link styles here
    &.active::before {
        // link ::before styles here
}`
```

`

Then you can use it

```
<li><MenuLink to="/" exact activeStyle={{color:"green"}}>Home</NavLink></li>
```